# How to show toast at Splash Screen

Tags: android

im working on an android application in which i have a main activity and Activity_splash.xml
which is my splash screen activity. what i want is when my app is launched, and if there is internet connection, the splash screen should appear for 3 seconds and after that main activity should launch and if there is No internet turned on, then it should show "No internet connection " toast and open wireless networks settings and after enabling wifi, if return button is pressed, user should be brought back to splash screen... hope this is understandable.. but my code is not working as im getting bunch of errors which are

1.`ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS` cannot be resolved or is not a field.
2.syntax error on token `"{",{ expected after this token (in line public class SplashScreen       extends` `Activity {)`
3.syntax error on token `"(",; expected and syntax error on token ")",;` expected (in line  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {)

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
if (!NetworkCheckClass.haveNetworkConnection(SplashActivity.this)) {
    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "No internet connection!",             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else {
    // your code if connection is available
} // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in OnCreate() of your activity :

```
if (!NetworkCheckClass.haveNetworkConnection(SplashActivity.this)) {
Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "No internet connection!",             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
}
else {
 // your code if connection is available
} // Splash screen timer
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
static ConnectivityManager cm;
AlertDialog dailog;
AlertDialog.Builder build;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    build = new Builder(Context); 

    if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting()
            || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .isConnectedOrConnecting()// if connection is
    // there screen goes
    // to next screen
    // else shows
    // message toast
    ) {
        Log.e("cm value", "" + cm.getAllNetworkInfo().toString());
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Internet is active", 2000)
                .show();
        Thread mythread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    sleep(5000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                            Yournextactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        mythread.start();
    } else {

        build.setMessage("This application requires Internet connection.Would you connect to internet ?");
        build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

            }
        });
        build.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                build.setMessage("Are sure you want to exit?");
                build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                build.setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                                SplashScreen.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                dailog = build.create();
                dailog.show();
            }
        });
        dailog = build.create();
        dailog.show();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: else write SplashScreen.this

Comment: still error  "type mismatch: cannot convert from animatorset.builder to alert dialog.builder"

Comment: did you find any fix?

Comment: i pressed ctrl + shift+o 100 times with no luck dude

Comment: please have a look , ive posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136486/how-to-detect-internet-and-open-wireless-settings

Comment: HELP!! if there is no internet, after enabling internet and pressing back button, i cannot get past the SplashScreen , its just showing splashscreen

Comment: here is ]the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136857/how-to-add-return-true-in-wireless-settings

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checknetworkavailability() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                // call your intent
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Check Your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                   @Override
                public void run() {

                 //  call settings intent

                   }

                }, 3000);

            }

}
```

use this method checknetworkavailability..