# how to add return=true in wireless settings

Tags: android

im working on a project and im stuck, what i want is after enabling wifi or internet, the back button(hardware button) should bring me back to `SplitScreen.xml` instead of closing the app  please dont give any code to add , as my code is working fine , insted ,correct my code

}}

Comment: Do not finish your activity if you want to come back again in it.

Comment: Your code is very complicating . You have written the dialog code for the yes/no button where you are calling the same `SplashScreen` activity from the `SplashScree` activity only. Why are you doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the behavior you want, move your call to open Wireless Settings to the MainActivity, and add a boolean variable to its Intent to indicate whether the Settings should be opened in MainActivity.onCreate.

**Total Redo Edit**

This is your SplashActivity.java. The only problem you should have is the layout name. I don't remember what you named it.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity
{
    static ConnectivityManager cm;
    AlertDialog dailog;
    AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);// checking
        build = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        // if connection is
        // there screen goes
        // to next screen
        // else shows
        // message
        if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting()
            || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            Log.e("cm value", "" + cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                  .isConnectedOrConnecting());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Internet is active", 2000).show();
            Thread mythread = new Thread() {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sleep(5000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                                                   MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            mythread.start();
        }
        else
        {
            build.setMessage("This application requires Internet connection. Would you connect to internet ?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                                                   MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("showSettings", true);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        finish();
                        //startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                    }
                });
            build.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        build.setMessage("Are sure you want to exit?");
                        build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        build.setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    finish();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                                                               SplashScreen.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                        dailog = build.create();
                        dailog.show();
                    }
                });
            dailog = build.create();
            dailog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is your MainActivity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ToggleButton toggle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglbtn1);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (toggle.isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boosting For Next 60 Minutes, Minimize the Application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boosting Turned Off",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean show = intent.getBooleanExtra("showSettings", false);

        if (show)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
        }
    }
}
```

Fix the layout name issue in SplashScreen and you should be good. I just ran this code and it performs as expected.

Comment: but the splashscreen disappeared

Comment: did you copy the main activity code?

Comment: ok i pasted both the activities, please see fast, ill have to delete them before somebody else steals my project

Comment: ok dude im trying this

Comment: can you tell me how to create a new alias in eclipse ? to sign my app, my old one is not letting me install my app

Comment: if i change the sleep time from 5 sec to any other value, will it effect the splashscreen time?

Comment: okie , i sent you a mail

Comment: mikey i need your help in my project